# How to explicitly use a standard function?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, loops

I'm running into a name collision with `iterate` and `count` standard function in the example below:

```
(defun svs-to-images (file)
  (with-open-file (stream file)
    (iterate:iter
      (iterate:for line #:= (read-line stream nil nil))
      (iterate:while line)
      (line-to-image
       (iterate:iter
         (iterate:for c #:in-string line)
         (iterate:with word)
         (iterate:with pos #:= 0)
         (iterate:with result #:= ; ---------\/ here
                       (make-array (list (1+ (count #\, line)))
                                   :element-type 'fixnum))
         (if (char= c #\,)
             (setf (aref result pos)
                   (parse-integer
                    (coerce (reverse word) 'string))
                   pos (1+ pos)
                   word nil)
             (setf word (cons c word)))
         (iterate:finally result)) 28))))
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
csv-parser.lisp:19:5:
  error: 
    during macroexpansion of
    (ITERATE:ITER
      (ITERATE:FOR LINE #:= ...)
      (ITERATE:WHILE LINE)
      ...).
    Use *BREAK-ON-SIGNALS* to intercept:

     Iterate, in (COUNT , LINE):
    Missing value for LINE keyword

Compilation failed.
```

And, if I understood it correctly, it is trying to use `count` as if it was the `count` driver from `iterate`, instead of the original function. How would I make it so that the correct `count` is used?

Comment: using cl:count does not help?

Comment: In the Iterate manual it says about clashes that one has to use UNIONING to prevent a clash with CL:UNION. Similar would be necessary for COUNT. But the manual uses both COUNT and COUNTING.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comp.lang.lisp Chris Riesbeck offered this as a workaround for a similar question a few years ago:

```
(remprop 'count 'iter::synonym)
```

From then you need to use COUNTING as the iterate clause. CL:COUNT then should refer to the Common Lisp function. You would need to recompile the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug/feature of how `iterate` processes its body.

You can use a version of `iterate` from [rutils](https://github.com/vseloved/rutils) - it uses keywords instead of plain symbols, so there will be no symbol clashes.

Comment: Actually, one of the 2 reasons to add `iterate` to `rutils` was the decline to accept a patch (not mine) from several years ago, which solved this particular problem, and I think, that this is a critical misfeature of it.